# Removing particular page from Frame cache

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am caching the `Page` using the following code:

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
```

But when I **navigate back from the page**, I want to **remove the particular page** from the cache.

I am using the following code to remove the `Page` from the cache, but it results in all pages being removed from the cache.

```
var frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
if (frame != null)
{
    var cacheSize = ((frame)).CacheSize;
    ((frame)).CacheSize = 0;
    ((frame)).CacheSize = cacheSize;
}
```

How can I remove only one particular page from the `Frame` cache?

Comment: did you find any solution? please share if you did.

Answer (score 0):

Generally one app contains one `Window`, and this `window` contains one `rootFrame`, in this `rootFrame` we can put several pages. When you create a UWP app, in the `OnLaunched` method, you can see this rootFrame.

```
var frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
```

this code means to get the `rootFrame` of this app, so I think you have used this to remove all pages from cache.

I've created a UWP app, and put a `splitview` in the `MainPage`, in the `Pane` of this control, I put a `Button` to navigate this page to Page1, and in the `Content` of this control, I put a `Frame`, and in this frame, I put a `Button` to navigate this frame to Page2:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Cache.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Cache"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>

                <VisualState>
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="450" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="RootSpiltView.DisplayMode" Value="CompactInline" />
                        <Setter Target="RootSpiltView.IsPaneOpen" Value="true" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState>
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="RootSpiltView.DisplayMode" Value="CompactInline" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <SplitView x:Name="RootSpiltView" OpenPaneLength="200" CompactPaneLength="50" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay" >

            <SplitView.Pane>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Height="auto">
                        <Button BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Click="Button_Click_Pane">
                            <Button.Content>
                                <TextBlock Text="&#xE700;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="24" />
                            </Button.Content>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="MainPage_Splitview_Pane" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="MainPageToPage1" Margin="0,80,0,0" Click="MainPageToPage1"/>
                </Grid>
            </SplitView.Pane>
            <SplitView.Content>
                <Frame x:Name="frame" Background="Transparent" Navigating="OnFrameNavigating" Navigated="OnFrameNavigated">
                    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="FrameToPage2" Click="FrameToPage2"/>
                </Frame>
            </SplitView.Content>
        </SplitView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage:

```
namespace Cache
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click_Pane(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.RootSpiltView.IsPaneOpen = !this.RootSpiltView.IsPaneOpen; 
        }

        private void OnFrameNavigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            string msg = "Frame's Navigating event happening, SourcePageType = {0}";
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(msg, e.SourcePageType);
        }

        private void OnFrameNavigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            string msg = "Frame's Navigated event happening, SourcePageType = {0}";
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(msg, e.SourcePageType);
        }

        private void FrameToPage2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
        }

        private void MainPageToPage1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page1));
        }
    }
}
```

When I is in Page 1, I click the button to navigate to MainPage and move the Page in rootframe from cache. And when I is in Page 2, I click the button to navigate to page1 in the frame, and move the page of this frame from cache:

Page1:

```
namespace Cache
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class Page1 : Page
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
        }

        private void NaviToMainPage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
            var rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            if (rootFrame != null)
            {
                var cacheSize = ((rootFrame)).CacheSize;
                ((rootFrame)).CacheSize = 0;
                ((rootFrame)).CacheSize = cacheSize;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Page2:

```
namespace Cache
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class Page2 : Page
    {
        public Page2()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
        }

        private void NaviToPage1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var frame = this.Frame;
            if (frame != null)
            {
                var cacheSize = ((frame)).CacheSize;
                ((frame)).CacheSize = 0;
                ((frame)).CacheSize = cacheSize;
            }
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page1));          
        }
    }
}
```

You can have a try.

Comment: Remark: You can put any *FrameworkElement* as window's content. In some cases the app can contain one page and multiple frames. Also it can run without pages/frames, everything depends on your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your remark, I've edited my answer, could you please help me to check, and correct me if I'm wrong? Thanks again!

Comment: My requirement is to cache the page data when I navigate forward form that page and remove that particular page from that cache when I navigate away from that page

Comment: for eg:-- if(Nagigatiomode=="Back) then remove that particular page from cache